# $\{ x_n \}$ is a bounded sequence. Let $x = \sup\{ x_n\}$ and $x_n < x$ $\forall n \Rightarrow$ there is a subsequence convergent to x

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Any thoughts? I know that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence

---

I also know that every bounded monotonic sequence is convergent.

---

I'm not sure I'm understanding, however, how $x=\sup\{x_n\}$ factors into this exactly.

Comment: Since $x=\sup\limits_{n}\{x_n\}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $x_n\in(x-\varepsilon,x]$. Can you continue now?

Comment: What if $x_n=\frac 1n$?

Comment: You also need to have $x_n<x$ for all $n$. Otherwise, consider sequence $1,0,0,0,0,\ldots$.

Comment: This is obviously false. For example the sequence $(1,0,0,0,...)$ has supremum $1$ but no subsequence converging to $1$. A slight modification is true - if this is a problem from a book probably you copied it wrong.

Comment: @richrow i added it to the title just now

Comment: @richrow also I'm not sure I'm seeing where to go after I state that $\exists x_n \in (x-\epsilon,x]$

Comment: @richrow but  you could have $x_n = x$ and $x_{m>n} < x - K$ for some positive $K$....

Comment: I think the question must also have a requirement that $x_k \ne x$ for any $k$.  Then the statement *is* true.

Comment: @fleablood This is written in the title, but indeed, the OP should ask to his question that $x_k < x$ for all $k$.

Comment: Yeah... missed it in the title.  Needs to be in the body as well.  Not sure if its a guideline for questions but I personally feel the *body* of all posts should contain a question in full.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sup\{x_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and it is given that $x_{n}<x$
for all $n$. The following proof requires recursion theorem (which
relies on the Axiom of Choice or weaker form because we are not working
beyond the ordinal $\omega$).

Let $n_{1}=1$. Suppose that $n_{1},n_{2},\ldots,n_{k}$ have been
chosen such that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots<n_{k}$. Let $\alpha_{k+1}=\max\left(\{x_{i}\mid1\leq i\leq n_{k}\}\cup\{x-\frac{1}{k+1}\}\right)$.
Clearly $\alpha_{k+1}<x$, so $\alpha_{k+1}$ is not an upper bound
of the set $\{x_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Hence, there exists $i$
such that $x_{i}>\alpha_{k+1}$. Observe that $i>n_{k}$. Denote such
$i$ by $n_{k+1}$. (Note that, in general, $i$ is not unique. If
there are more than one such $i$, we choose anyone from them and
call it $n_{k+1}$.) Now, it is clear that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$,
$x_{n_{1}}<x_{n_{2}}<\ldots<x$, and $x_{n_{k}}>x-\frac{1}{k}$ for
$k>1$. Hence, $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow x$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Show that you can define inductively a strictly increasing function $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by :
$$\varphi(0) = 0$$

and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$,
$$\varphi(n+1) = \min \lbrace k > \varphi(n) \text{ }|\text{ } x- \frac{1}{n+1} \leq x_k \leq x \rbrace.$$

Then show that you have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_{\varphi(n)} = x$$

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have added the stipulation that $x_k = \sup x_n = x$ is never acheive

let $r_1 = 1$ then there must be an $x_k$ so that $\sup x_n -1 < x_k \le \sup x_n$.  Let $w_1$ be the *very* first $x_k \in (\sup x_n - 1, \sup x_n]$.  Then as $w_1 \ne \sup x_n$ we can let $r_2 =\sup x_n - w_1 > 0$.

There must be an $x_j$ so that $w_1 =\sup x_n - r_2 < x_j \le \sup x_n$.  Let $w_2$ be the very first $x_j \in (w_1, \sup x_n]$.  (Note as $w_1$ was the very first $x_k > \sup x_n -1$ then $x_j$ must occur later; i.e. $j > k$.) And again as $w_2 < \sup x_n$ we have $x_n - w_2 > 0$.

We repeat this indefinitely.  Let $r_{m+1}= \sup x_n - w_m$ and let $w_{m+1}$ be the very first $x_k\in (w_m, \sup x_n]$.

The sequence $w_n$ is an increasing sub sequence of $x_n$ so that is bounded above by $x$.  As every increasing sequence that is bounded above converges $w_n$ converges.... argh ...  It doesnt need to converge to $x$.  It *could* converge to something less than $x$.

We need $r_k \to 0$ as well.

FInal answer:

> Let $r_1 = 1$, $w_1$ be the very first $x_k$ so that $x - 1< x_k \le x$.  Let $r_2 = \min (\frac 12, x-w_1)$.  Let $w_2$ be the very first $x_k$ so that $x-r_1 < x_k \le x$.

> Recursively define $r_m = \min (\frac 1{m}, x-w_m)$ and let $w_{m+1}$ be the very first $x_k$ so that $x-r_m < x_k \le x$.  That is a well defined subsequence as for every $w_m = x_{k_m}$ and $w_n= x_{k_n}$ when $n > m$ we will have $k_n > k_m$ (this is why taking the *very* first $x_k$ so that $x-r_m < x_k \le x$ was essential).

> And $w_n \to x$.

> Pf:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac 1N < \epsilon$.  If $n > N$ then $r_n < \frac 1N < \epsilon$ and $x-\epsilon < x-r_n < w_{n+1} < x$.  So $w_n \to x$.

=====

Needn't be true.  The intuition should be this:  A convergent sequence has it's "tail" end approach a value.  The $\sup$ ins a value as high as any value gets and some values must be near it.  But that need not occur at the tail end.

So for example if the sup is $3$ at a $x_{15} = 3$ but other wise you have $a_k$ "all over the place" but never getting close to the $3$ ever again then no infinite subsequence converges to $3$.

.....

More challenging would be to show that if $\sup x_n= x$. but no sequences converge to $x$ then there must be a $k$ where $x_k = x$.

......

Or alternatively: if we claim $\sup x_n = x$ but there are *no* $k$ so that $x_k =x$ then it must be that there *IS* some subsequence converging to $x$.

I'll let you think about that for a few hours and post my proof of that this afternoon. (use richrow's hint in the comment).

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:**

If $\;\left\{x_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is a sequence bounded above in $\;\mathbb{R}\;,$

$x=\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{x_n\right\}\in\mathbb{R}\;$ and $\;x_n<x\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

then there exists a subsequence $\left\{x_{n_k}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=x\;.$

**Proof:**

Let $\;\epsilon_1=1>0\;.$

By applying the second property of supremum, we get that there exists $\;n_1\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;x-\epsilon_1<x_{n_1}\;.$

Let $\;\epsilon_2=\min\big\{\frac{1}{2}, x-\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_1}\}\big\}>0\;.$

By applying the second property of supremum, we get that there exists $\;n_2\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;x-\epsilon_2<x_{n_2}\;.$

Since $\;\epsilon_2\le x-\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_1}\}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_1}\}\le x-\epsilon_2<x_{n_2}\;,\;$ hence $\;n_2>n_1\;.$

$.........................................\\
.........................................$

Let $\;\epsilon_k=\min\big\{\frac{1}{k}, x-\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_{k-1}}\}\big\}>0\;.$

By applying the second property of supremum, we get that there exists $\;n_k\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;x-\epsilon_k<x_{n_k}\;.$

Since $\;\epsilon_k\le x-\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_{k-1}}\}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_{k-1}}\}\le x-\epsilon_k<x_{n_k}\;,\;$ hence $\;n_k>n_{k-1}\;.$

$.........................................\\
.........................................$

Consequently there exists the sequence of positive integers $\;\left\{n_k\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;n_k>n_{k-1}\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$

and $\;x-\cfrac{1}{k}\le x-\epsilon_k<x_{n_k}<x\quad$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

It means that there exists the subsequence $\;\left\{x_{n_k}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ such that $\;x-\cfrac{1}{k}<x_{n_k}<x\quad$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

and, by applying the squeeze theorem, it follows that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_{n_k}=x\;.$